# Python: How can I check if a set of randomly generated numbers exist in a list using indexing?

Tags: python, list, indexing

Consider:

```
import random

lst1 = []
lst2 = []
comparison_results = []

n = int(input('Step a: How many numbers in each list? '))

for i in range(n):
    number1 = random.randint(1, 15)
    number2 = random.randint(1, 15)
    lst1.append(number1)
    lst2.append(number2)

    if lst1[i] > lst2[i]:
        comparison_results.append(f'{number1} : First List')
    elif lst1[i] < lst2[i]:
        comparison_results.append(f'{number2} : Second List')

combined_lst = lst1 + lst2
print(f'Step b: First List {lst1}')
print(f'Step c: Second List {lst2}')
print('Step d: Larger number in each comparison:')
for result in comparison_results:
    print(result)
print(f'Step e: Combined List: {combined_lst}')

for i in range(len(combined_lst)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(combined_lst)):
        if combined_lst[i] > combined_lst[j]:
            combined_lst[i], combined_lst[j] = combined_lst[j], combined_lst[i]

print(f'Step f: Sorted List: {combined_lst}')
print('Step g:')
print(f'First three elements: {combined_lst[:3]}')
print(f'Last three elements: {combined_lst[-3:]}')

new_num = []
for z in range(4):
    four_random = random.randint(1, 15)
    new_num.append(four_random)
    print(new_num)
```

I need to generate four random numbers (new_num) and check to see if those numbers are in my combined list (combined_list).

I tried a method comparing the index at 0, but I am not sure how to check all.

Answer (score 0):

The naive approach is:

> Loop over `new_num`. For each element `n`, go through `combined_list`
> and check if any of its elements is equal to `n`.

This is called a [linear search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search) and is already built into the Python `list` type with the `in` operator:

```
for num in new_num:
    # this performs a linear search on combined_list
    if num in combined_list:
        print(f"Number {num} is in combined_list!")
    else:
        print(f"Number {num} is not in combined_list")
```

However, if `new_num` or `combined_list` are long, this approach can be very slow. Your average runtime performance is `O(len(new_num) * len(combined_list))`.

Instead, you can convert `combined_list` to a `set`. The `set` type also supports the `in` operator, but much more efficiently than a `list` (checking if a `set` contains a specific value always takes approximately the same, constant time, no matter its size).

Your code becomes:

```
combined_set = set(combined_list)
for num in new_num:
    if num in combined_set:
        print(f"Number {num} is in combined_list!")
    else:
        print(f"Number {num} is not in combined_list")
```

Note that to convert a list to a set, you still need to iterate over the entire list. However, you only have to do it once.
Your average performance thus becomes `O(len(new_num) + len(combined_list))`, which is (most likely) faster than the naive approach.